# inline asm, 32b cpu registers assigned for 64b variable

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly

There is 32b CPU. In order to work with 64b variables compiler assigns 2 registers let say for example `r0` is 'var64b_low' and `r1` is 'var64b_high'.
Is there a way to know what registers are allocated for 64b variable in inline asm. I want to get something like that:

```
asm volatile(
    "add  ll,  %[a], %[b]  \n\t"   // ll is LSB 32b of var64
    "add  hh,  %[a], %[b]  \n\t"   // hh is MSB 32b of var64
    :[some clobber for 64b output value]
    :[a]"r"(a), [b]"r"(b)
    :
);
```

Thanks.

PS: Right now I write low and high part back in memory but I want to avoid these extra savings/loadings.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2006-06/msg00003.html)?

Comment: Yeap, exactly like that. Could you put it as an answer, please. BTW, are there something similar to `%<n>` & `%H<n>` for MicroBlaze inline assembly?

Comment: Done.  I don't know anything about MicroBlaze.  However, you might page thru the gcc code for it.  In particular, check out the [print_operand](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/microblaze/microblaze.c?revision=246020&view=markup#l2144) code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [this post to the gcc-help mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2006-06/msg00003.html):

> On ARM the modifiers for accessing 64-bit types are
>
> - %<n> The lowest numbered register of a pair
> - %H The highest numbered register of a pair
> - %Q The register containing the least significant
>     part of the 32-bit  value
> - %R The register containing the most
>     significant part of the 32-bit value
>
> Why so many?  Well it depends on whether you want your code to compile
>   correctly for big-endian as well as little-endian systems.

The post then contains an example:

> ```
> int64_t        a,b,r;
> asm(
>      "adds   %Q0,    %Q1,    %Q2"            "\n\t"
>      "adds   %R0,    %R1,    %R2"            "\n\t"
>      "mov    %R0,    %R0,    rrx"            "\n\t"
>      "mov    %Q0,    %Q0,    rrx"
>      : "=&r" (r) : "r" (a), "r" (b) : "cc" );
> ```
>
> Note the use of =&r in the constraint for the variable 'r'.  This
>   ensures  that your input operands won't be corrupted before they have
>   been fully  read.

I don't have an ARM setup, so I cannot confirm.  However, Richard Earnshaw (the author of that post) is the ARM port maintainer for gcc, so he presumably knows what he is talking about.

It is probably also worth mentioning that (unlike the [x86 modifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers)) these ARM modifiers are undocumented, which usually means that they are also unsupported.  Depending upon unsupported features (for any product) is risky, so use with caution!

Comment: I'd swear that those x86 modifiers were also undocumented just a short time ago. They were definitely not there when I first learned the syntax a couple years back Lots of big improvements were made recently to GCC's inline-assembly documentation; were you involved in that? If so, great job!

Comment: @CodyGray Yep, that was me. The asm page at the time was so bad I couldn't stand it, so I ended up re-writing it to (essentially) what you see now. And creating the Basic asm page.  And cleaning up the related pages (register vars, asm labels, etc). And fiddling with most every page that references inline asm. I (intentionally) didn't doc all the modifiers (since "doc'ed" means "supported"), but I did the ones that seemed the most useful (sorry no ARM, but x86 is all I know). So now inline asm is much easier to use. Wait... What have I done!??!